# Cordova Media plugin doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, cordova-media-plugin

everyone!
I have successfully created list of medias with cordova-plugin-media, but when I trigger the recording, I get error;

```
{message: "Failed to start recording using AVAudioRecorder", code: 1}
```

I can't even imagine what could have happened and why this error has occurred(((

Here is my JS code

```
(function() {
 "use strict";
  angular.module('app.services')
  .factory('soundService', function($q) {
    var fileDirectory = null,
        mediasForPlay = [],
        currentMedia = null;

    return {
      createDir: function(segments) {

//get dir

        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.cacheDirectory, function (dir) { // create All segments for video at once
          fileDirectory = dir;
          segments = segments.map(function (elem) {

//here we create files for recording

            return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
              fileDirectory.getFile(elem.id + '.wav', {create: true, exclusive: false},
                  function (file) {resolve(file)},
                  function(err) {reject(err)});
            });
          });
          $q.all(segments).then(function(data) {  

//transform it to media 

            mediasForPlay = data.map(function(elem) {
              var url = elem.nativeURL.replace('file://', ''),
              media = new Media(url, function() {console.log('success'); media.release()}, function (err) {console.log(err)});
              return media;
            });
          });
        })
      },
      startRecord: function(segmentId, index) {
        currentMedia = mediasForPlay[index];

//here we get an error   

        currentMedia.startRecord();
      }
    }
  })
    })();
```

Comment: Did you tried using cordova.file.externalRootDirectory or  cordova.file.externalDataDirectory instead of cordova.file.cacheDirectory ?

Comment: yes, I tried, but anyway this bug occurs(((

Comment: Check out this link on file operations - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations as i feel that this issue could be related to file creation. Also ensure to latest file plugin

Comment: than you. I will try